# IFC: Add Unit (IfcUnit) to IfcPropertySingleValue

Tags: python, scripting, ifc

A python script produces an IFC-file wherein the following line appears several times:

```
PropertySingleValueWriter = ifcfile.createIfcPropertySingleValue("{}".format(V), "{}".format(k), ifcfile.create_entity("IfcText", str((val["{}".format(k)]))), None)
```

This produces (as one represantive example)

```
#598=IFCPROPERTYSINGLEVALUE('Object','Wall',IFCTEXT('12.3'),$);
```

The last argument `None` stands for the unit which, in this case, has not been given yet and was translated as `$` in the output IFC-file. The unit known by line

```
#7=IFCSIUNIT(*,.LENGTHUNIT.,$,.METRE.);
```

in the IFC-file should now be inserted instead. This can be done manually in the IFC-file by writing `#7` into the line,

```
#598=IFCPROPERTYSINGLEVALUE('Object','Wall',IFCTEXT('12.3'),#7);
```

Using an adapted python script would be much more efficient. However, I have not found the correct scripting yet to add `#7` as a simple text. My attempts have been so far,

```
[1] PropertySingleValueWriter = ifcfile.createIfcPropertySingleValue("{}".format(V), "{}".format(k), ifcfile.create_entity("IfcText", str((val["{}".format(k)]))), "#7")
[2] PropertySingleValueWriter = ifcfile.createIfcPropertySingleValue("{}".format(V), "{}".format(k), ifcfile.create_entity("IfcText", str((val["{}".format(k)]))), "'#7'")
[3] PropertySingleValueWriter = ifcfile.createIfcPropertySingleValue("{}".format(V), "{}".format(k), ifcfile.create_entity("IfcText", str((val["{}".format(k)]))), "'{}'".format("#7"))
[4] PropertySingleValueWriter = ifcfile.createIfcPropertySingleValue("{}".format(V), "{}".format(k), ifcfile.create_entity("IfcText", str((val["{}".format(k)]))), ifcfile.create_entity("IfcText", "#7"))
```

They either produce an error ([1], [2], [3]) or explicitly write `IFCTEXT('#7')` ([4]) into the IFC-file which is not interpretable as a connection to the line `#7`.

Which is the correct scripting in the python file in order to get the connection to line `#7` as achievable by manual editing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ifcfile.by_id(7)`

so your code becomes

```
PropertySingleValueWriter = ifcfile.createIfcPropertySingleValue("{}".format(V), "{}".format(k), ifcfile.create_entity("IfcText", str((val["{}".format(k)]))), ifcfile.by_id(7))
```